# variable is not shareable in http $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$http({
    url: "php/InsertTab.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            'userId': userId,
        },
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        myVar = data;

        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    });

console.log(myVar);
```

can variable myVar be share / be access outside the scope of $http? I wrote console.log(myVar) outside it returned blank?

Comment: why do you don't want to try :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: Yes it can, but at the moment you are trying to access it, the success handler hasn't been executed yet. Ajax is **asynchronous**.

Answer (score 0):

u have to use angular $q service in order to use myVar outside of $http.
try reading in this page  : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q