# $http success scope finished loading possible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$http({
    url: "php/InsertTab.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            'userId': userId,
        },
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        myVar = data;

        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    });
```

how to wait success scope done loading? there's no .done in angularjs's $http

Comment: success is called if the operation went ok (after it is done).

Comment: possible duplicate of [variable is not shareable in http $scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579250/variable-is-not-shareable-in-http-scope) -- please don't ask questions twice.

Comment: Do you want to do something after either a success or error?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.success` method:

> .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
>
> ```
>   // this callback will be called asynchronously
>   // when the response is available
>
> })
> ```

Comment: what? I used success in my above code, look carefully

Comment: @user3522469 this is the answer to the question. The success function is called when the xmlrequest is done and got a positive response. If you do not understand it you need to start searching and reading

Comment: Ah, sorry - I saw only ".error"! Then what is your question / problem?!

Comment: @RonniSkansing I want to do something after success, how?

Comment: @user3522469: By executing whatever you want to do inside `success`.

Comment: @user3522469 the questions is very vague, how can it be answered other then put it in the bottom of success or push a event and make something else listen to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean updating scope, you can directly assign to scope from the success callback.

```
$http({
    url: "php/InsertTab.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            'userId': userId,
        },
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        $scope.myVar = data;

        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    });
```

If you need to show a loading indicator or so, you can use the promise API, which provides a `then(success, error)` method, like that:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.ajaxLoading = true;

    $scope.ajaxComplete = function() {
        $scope.ajaxLoading = false;
    };

    $http({
        url: "php/InsertTab.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                'userId': userId,
            },
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            $scope.myVar = data;

            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        }).then($scope.ajaxComplete, $scope.ajaxComplete);
}
```

You can later make this generic using AJAX interceptors. See the AJAX documentation page:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: so then is after success? if yes then that's what I want.

Comment: It depends on the order of setting, so if `success` was called first,  the function you passed to it should be called first